# Why does Blender crash when I switch scenes?

Tags: scene

In the attached .blend file, when I switch from the scene that I have named "Outer" to the scene that I have named "Inner," Blender immediately crashes. I can't find another situation like this one on BSE (although I have tried solutions for crashes caused by other methods). Can anyone tell me how I can open the Inner scene. It has most of my work in it.

I just realized that I can't upload the .blend file to blend-exchange because it is too big. I can't make it smaller without getting into the Inner scene. So, if anyone has any suggestions about how to decrease the file size without accessing the bulk of the work (the Inner scene), please let me know.

Comment: If blender is crashing, then this is a bug. Consider [sending a report in to the developers](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1377/best-place-to-put-bug-reports)

Comment: If Blender crashes then it is likely a bug. In the mean time create a new clean file and try appending your data from that original file's scene to try to recover your data. If it still crashes try appending one by one until you find the culprit

Comment: If you can find a way to make your file smaller, I have a feeling you will have found the way to make your crashes stop... It is fairly easy to create scenes that surpass the resources of your computer...